# Drupal CKEditor HTML tags

Tags: drupal, ckeditor

When I apply bold CKEditor wraps the text in  tags. When I select italic it puts  tags. My default input format is Full HTML (also when creating content). In the Wysiwyg profiles I set CKEditor for Full HTML input. In the configuration of CKEditor, under Cleanup and output I selected Convert  tags to styles.
This should use inline CSS, but it doesn't. It puts HTML that don't change the text. It stays like it's not formatted. What's wrong?

Comment: can you be more specific about the tags you need styled?

Answer (score 1):

Filtered HTML should force it to display the content correctly using the html tags.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! HTML filtering was set correctly, but I messed up my styles with CSS reset. I just removed "font: inherit;" from my CSS and now it works. :)